# Play, Ebean, Jackson: How do I serialize the id of a parent model, instad of the complete model?

Tags: java, json, playframework, jackson, ebean

I have 2 models, Frame and Camera. **Many Frames can belong to one Camera:**

```
public class Frame extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    public Camera camera;
}

public class Camera extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String name;
}
```

When I serialize a Frame using Jackson, I get:

```
{
    id: 1,
    camera: {
        id: 1
        name: "Cam 2"
    }
}
```

**I would like to serialize a Frame with only the camera's id:**

```
{
    id: 1,
    camera: 1
}
```

I am searching Jackson's annotation documentation, but there are quite a few descriptions that I don't understand right away, so I'm probably missing something.

Comment: Why don't you have a `Collection<Frame>` in your `Camera` instead (or a `List<Frame>`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured this one out myself.

```
public class Frame extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    public Camera camera;

    @Transient
    @JsonProperty(value="camera")
    public Camera camera_id;
}
```

This generates the results I was after. It works because the underlaying db field is named "camera_id". This name is auto generated, but could also be specified.

This "feels" like a hack, and I suspect that there's another way of doing it. If anyone have any other suggestion, I'll change the accepted answer :)